# Why does my Joomla site redirect every menu item to login?

Tags: joomla

I have trashed the login module and none are currently published, yet every page is sending users to the login page. Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means either all your menu item Access is set to **registered, super user or special**

OR

In Global Configuration under site menu you have set  Default Access Level 
to **registered, super user or special**.

Change the Access to public and your users can view the page.